# does apple's wiki server support mathematical syntax?

Tags: wiki, apple

In MediaWiki, tex (or latex) extensions can be integrated (even if to be so hard!) in order to support mathematical syntax. I could not see any information that wiki server can support mathematical syntax in it. 
Can anyone know that kind of mathematical syntax support in snow leopard server / wiki server?
thanks.

hakan.

Answer (score 0):

None. All you could do is use something like LaTeXIt and use images instead of formulas.